# Revo uninstaller ridiculous memory usage

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, revo-uninstaller

I'm using revo uninstaller pro to uninstall around 130 programs in one batch. It does them one at a time, so I'd imagine no harm could happen. Though I felt my computer being very slow, so I checked task manager and Revo was eating up around 6GB of physical ram (out of my 8GB), and about 9GB commit. Is this expected? Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Edit: After my computer was frozen for nearly half an hour, task manager updated showing Revo's commit to be almost 15GB.

Comment: report it to the developer and don't use it

Comment: Instead of spending that much time uninstalling 130 programs why not re-format and reload windows you will be done much sooner.  Microsoft has a rollup for windows 7 that takes you from SP1 to April 2016 in 1 go.  Then you will only have a handfull of updates left to install, and re-install your stuff.

Comment: If you regularly try software to test it and then uninstall it, then you should probably do that in a VM (virtual machine) so you don't have deal with that much junk on your primary OS.  You can take a snapshot and roll the VM back to pristine condition at will with much less effort.